# Creating a table without pre-defining a number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any way to issue a mysql statement to create a table without having to assign the number of columns? I am working with the MySQL C API for grabbing some variables and then storing them in a table. The issue that I am encountering is that I have to create the table (obviously) before inserting the variables into the table. These variables sometimes are structures (two, three or four variables into a single table), so I am looking for a way of not having to say:

`CREATE TABLE Structures(ID varchar(10) primary key, name varchar(25))`

but creating a table on where any number of columns can be inserted?

Let me know if I am being a bit vague in here.

Comment: Based on a lot of experience, I have a bad hunch that whatever you are trying to do is a bad idea -- one of the so-called `anti-patterns` out there.  If you can explain your end goal, perhaps better solutions can be offered.

Comment: SQL is column-oriented. You can alter the table. You can store a representation of multiple values in a single column. Either way, there's a reasonable chance you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I edited the post to add more info

Comment: Does it have to be MySQL (or any other standard *SQL)? If not, you can use some NoSQL/document-based etc solutions which support dynamic schemas. And if it has to be relational (e.g. MySQL) you can use the EAV pattern in which you'd have tables like: `var_int`, `var_float`, `var_varchar`, ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can however add columns at runtime using `ALTER TABLE`.

However, personally, I wouldn't recommend that. You should know what your database looks like, before you start implementing it.

Comment: This could be a potentially good solution.. Is there any disadvantages on doing this?

Comment: Altering a table afterwards can take a long time, if your table is already filled with data. However, I'm still not sure, if you should go with an SQL database for your thesis. A No-SQL database (e.g. MongoDB) might fit better for this.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to code this is to use two tables and a one-to-many between them.

For instance,  you might have a tables like this - pcode,

```
table experiment
  experiment_id: long
  experiment_header: varchar(50)


table experiemnt_data
  experiemnt_data_id: long
  experiment_id: long
  key: varchar(20)
  value: long

 @id = insert into experiment  (experiment_header) value("test run")

 insert into experiment_data  (experiment_id, key, value) value(@id, 'x', 1)
 insert into experiment_data  (experiment_id, key, value) value(@id, 'y', 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

AS @Mark and @attis said:

> You can't. You can however add columns at runtime using ALTER
>   TABLE.
>
> However, personally, I wouldn't recommend that. You should know what
>   your database looks like, before you start implementing it.

I think the best solution could be:
Create two tables :

- `column` with (`id`, `name`)
- `values` with (`id`, `column_id`, `value`)

then you just have to join them to easily get you results, and you can easily add others "columns"

You can also store everything in `values` table, but your data may be inconsistent, and, in my mind, it's faster to look for a number than to compare strings (table lock, index etc...)

I wanted to comment @Mark post, but can't (reputation too low)